# Parsing USB Serial Data to Usable Variables

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, usb

I have a setup where an Android and Arduino device are communicating data via USB. I have the Arduino regularly read data from my vehicle and send it to the Android device, such as so (either of these formats are viable):

XML:

```
<instance>
    <vin> A13GF12345NFH </vin>
    <speed> 78 </speed>
    <runtime> 1425 </runtime>
    <distance> 23 </distance>
</instance>
```

JSON:

```
{
    "vin" : "A13GF12345NFH",
    "speed" : "78",
    "runtime" : "1425",
    "distance" : "23"
}
```

I receive the data as a byte array and then I convert it into a string. Given that my stringified XML (or JSON) data is a variable `data` of type string, how could I get the variables `vin`, `speed`, `runtime`, and `distance` as described in the message? I will use whatever data format is easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JSONObject class as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html).

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(dataString);
String vin = jo.getString("vin");
long runtime = jo.getLong("runtime");
```